# Having to use a fully qualified class name

Tags: c#, .net, using, using-statement, using-directives

For some reason, after adding a reference to `MySql.Data` and adding `using MySql.Data;`, I'm unable to type `new MySqlConnection()` - instead I'm having to type `new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();`.

I can resolve this by adding this to the top of my class:

```
using MySqlClient = MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using MySqlConnection = MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection;
using MySqlException = MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException;
```

But how can I access *all* classes within `MySqlClient` without having to alias them? I haven't seen this behaviour before.

Comment: Havye you tried `new MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter That works (thanks to the top line of that block).

Comment: if you don't want an alias, why are you using an alias ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

Now this works:

```
using(var con = new MySqlConnection("..."))
{
    // ...
}
```

You cannot use "sub-namespaces" during initialization of an object with `new`. So this is not allowed:

```
using MySql.Data;

// ...
using(var con = new MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("..."))
{
    // ...
}
```

because `MySqlClient` is considered to be a class instead of a part of the namespace. That's why it cannot be resolved and it needs to be qualified fully:

```
using(var con = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("..."))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It's been a long day, how I didn't notice the alias on the top line, idk. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need the entire namespace.

`using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;`